# Compute $\lim_{n\to\infty} nx_n$

Tags: calculus

Let $(x_n)_{n\ge2}$, $x_2>0$, that satisfies recurrence $x_{n+1}=\sqrt[n]{1+n x_n}-1, n\ge 2$. Compute $\lim_{n\to\infty} nx_n$.
It's clear that $x_n\to 0$, and probably Stolz theorem would be helpful. Is it really necessary to use this theorem?

Comment: Why is it clear that $x_n\to 0$?

Comment: @PeterTamaroff that thing can be proved in many ways. For instance, Bernoulli inequality shows the sequence is strictly decreasing, and combined with the fact that $x_n>0$ for all $n\ge2$ leads you exactly to that conclusion.

Comment: @PeterTamaroff: $1+nx_n=(1+x_{n+1})^n>1+nx_{n+1}$, so the sequence $(x_n)$ is decreasing, with a limit $L$. Now $(1+nx_n)^{1/n}\to1+L$. Using $n^{1/n}\to1$ (and the boundedness of $(x_n)$) you quickly conclude that $L=0$.

Comment: Hmm... I found another way, but it is too complicated. I keep @HaraldHanche-Olsen 's way.

Comment: @PeterTamaroff $1 \le (1+nx_n)^{1/n}\le (1+C n )^{1/n} \rightarrow \text{root test for the right side}$

Comment: @Abrilliantcrazygirl The fact the sequence is strictly decreasing and is bounded by zero does not guarantee the limit of the sequence actually equals zero. Is this how you meant it?

Comment: @David agree, it's not enough. I didn't mention the elementary fact of taking the limit in the recurrence relation. (it seemed obvious to me - straightforward by root test). Actually, one has a lot of options.

Comment: The answer by @mike, which he deleted shortly after posting it, shows that the limit, if it exists and is finite, must be zero. (I think his answer is sound, though it takes a bit of work to see that. A pity he deleted it, even if it was incomplete.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $(1+x)^n\geqslant nx+1$ we obtain that $x_n\geqslant x_{n+1}$. As the sequence is positive and decreasing, it must converge. Call this limit $\ell$. Consider the non-negative functions $$f_n(x)=\frac{\log(1+nx)}n$$

They have the property that $$\log(1+x_{n+1})=f_n(x_n)$$

Since $x_n$ is decreasing, and since the $f_n$ are decreasing, meaning that $f_{n+1}\leq f_n$, yet each one of them is increasing, meaning $f_n(x)\leq f_n(y)$ if $x\leq y$, we have $$f_{n+1}(x_{n+1})\leq f_n(x_{n+1})\leq f_n(x_n) $$

The limit thus exists. We would like to argue that $f_n(x_n)\to 0$. Since $x_n$ decreases and is non-negative, we can work inside a compact interval $[0,M]$. In this interval, the continuous $f_n$ converge monotonically to $0$, thus by Dini's theorem, they converge uniformly. Thus, $\{f_n\}_{n\geqslant 1}$ is an equicontinuous family, whence $$\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(x_n)=\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(\ell)=0$$

But then $\log(1+\ell)=0\implies \ell =0$.

**Hint**  Let ${\left( {1 + {x_{n + 1}}} \right)^n} = 1 + n{x_n} = {y_n}$. Since $x_n\to 0$ we may expand $$\log \left( {1 + {x_{n + 1}}} \right) = {x_{n + 1}} + {x_{n + 1}}O\left( {{x_{n + 1}}} \right)$$ for sufficiently large $n$, so if we let $y_n-1=\omega_n$; $$\log \left( 1+\omega_n \right) = \frac{n}{{n + 1}} \omega_{n+1} + n{x_{n + 1}}O\left( {{x_{n + 1}}} \right)$$

Thus if the limit exists, it must be $0$.

---

Let $\mathscr F=\{f_i\}_{i\in I}$ be a family of functions $f_i:A\to\Bbb R$. We say $\mathscr F$ is equicontinuous on $A$ if for each $\epsilon>0$ there exists $\delta >0$ such that for each $x,y\in A$ and $f_i\in\mathscr F$ $$|x-y|<\delta\implies |f_i(x)-f_i(y)|<\epsilon$$

Note every function in an equicontinuous family of functions is automatically uniformly continuous, for example.

Comment: (Take the proof that $x_n\to 0$ as a jest, if you may.)

Comment: Indeed. That last bit is essentially @mike's argument done more carefully. I was writing it up myself, but you beat me to it.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen Yes, that is true.

Comment: A quick numerical experiment indicates that $nx_n$ decreases, but rather slowly. I can't quite see how to prove it, though.

Comment: @PeterTamaroff maybe you wanna add some things on what an "equicontinuous" function is.

Comment: @Abrilliantcrazygirl Done.

Comment: I should say: $nx_n$ seems to decrease *eventually*. If $x_2$ is small, the $nx_n$ increases to begin with, then starts to decrease. So a proof of this is likely somewhat subtle.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the function $$f_n(t)=\Bigl(1+\frac{t}{n+1}\Bigr)^n,\qquad t\ge0, \quad n=2,3,\ldots$$
Clearly (convexity, value and derivative at $t=0$, growth), there is a $t_n>0$ so that $f_n(t)<1+t$ when $0<t<t_n$, and $f_n(t)>1+t$ when $t>t_n$. Now
$$f_n(t)\ge 1+\frac{n}{n+1}t+\frac{n(n-1)}{2(n+1)^2}t^2=1+\frac{nt}{n+1}\Bigl(1+\frac{n-1}{2(n+1)}t\Bigr)>1+t$$
provided $$\frac{n-1}{2(n+1)}t>\frac1n,$$
and it follows that $$\limsup_{n\to\infty}nt_n\le2.$$

Whenever $nx_n>t_n$ we have $f_n(nx_n)>1+nx_n$, that is
$$1+\frac{nx_n}{n+1}>\sqrt[n]{1+nx_n}=1+x_{n+1}$$
and so $(n+1)x_{n+1}<nx_n$.

Even when this is not the case, $x_{n+1}<x_n$, so that $(n+1)x_{n+1}<nx_n+x_n$.

It is possible that $nx_n>t_n$ for all large $n$. If so, the sequence $(nx_n)$ is decreasing, so it has a limit, which must be zero (see the answer by Peter Tamaroff).

If $nx_n\le t_n$ for arbitrarily large $n$, then for such $n$, $(n+1)x_{n+1}<t_n+x_n$,
which goes to zero as $n\to\infty$ (see the comments for an argument that $x_n\to0$). So in any case, $nx_n\to0$ as $n\to\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

With $y_n=nx-n$, we have the recurrence
$$ y_{n+1} = n(\sqrt[n]{1+y_n}-1)$$
Note that for $h>0$, we have $(1+h)^n>1+nh$, hence  $\sqrt[n]{1+h}<1+\frac hn$, which makes $\{y_n\}$ a decreasing sequence, bounded from below by $0$, hence convergent. Let $L$ be the limit.

With $f_n(t):=\exp(t\ln(1+y_n))$ note that
$$ y_{n+1}=\frac{f_n(1/n)-f_n(0)}{1/n}=f_n'(\tau_n)$$
with $0<\tau_n<\frac1n$. Since $f_n'(t)=\ln(1+y_n)f_n(t)$, this gives us
$$ y_{n+1}=\ln(1+y_n)\exp(\tau_n\ln(1+ y_n)).$$
The right hand side is continuous as a function in $\tau$ and $y$, hence in the limit, when $\tau_n\to 0$ and $y_n\to L$, we find
$$ L=\ln(1+L)\cdot 1$$
which has the only solution $$L=0.$$

Comment: Is there a misprint at the start? Did you mean $y_n=nx_n$? But then the recurrence becomes $y_{n+1}=(n+1)\bigl(\sqrt[n]{1+y_n}-1\bigr)$. Put bluntly, I don't understand your proof.